# Difference of Rates in ECM

Tags: differences, ecm, variable

I am setting up a model to predict something using Error Correction Model (see pic. to get a general view about the model itself).

[image]

Some of my $X$ variables are the **interest spread between the A and B govt bill (Sprd)** (e.g. 90 day). At this point I have a practical question:

Regarding $\triangle Sprd$, what is the standard procedure to estimate it?:

1. take the difference as a simple $Sprd_{t}-Sprd_{t-1}$
2. or apply $Sprd_{t}/Sprd_{t-1}-1$

As far as I know, the invariant of this kind of variable are option 1 (Meucci´s book), but I am not really sure if this is valid is in this case.

I would appreciate any advice about this

Comment: Hi: you need to be clear and precise about what the response is and the variables that you think ( or want to test if ) the response is effected by. Then you can define the variables accordingly. saying interest rates and spread is not helpful because variables can't be stock variables or flow variables.  Maybe you mean the return of the 10 year note minus the return of the 1 year ? or the daily closing log price of stock A minus the daily closing log price of stock B etc.

Comment: @mlofton edited to clarify X variable. Thx

Comment: If $\Delta X_t = Sprd_t/Sprd_{t-1} - 1$, then what is $X_t$?  Presumably you want its lagged value to appear in the error-correction term.